# Can I hide http calls from the network tab in Developer tools?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular 2 app that polls a server to check for new notifications, however, it shows up in the network tab as http post calls. Is there was to hide the polling from the code? I used Observable.interval to poll the server.

Comment: no you can't **really** hide http calls, it would be a security issue ... But for debug purpose on your side you can filter some http calls yes.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome dev tools doesn't allow to filter requests by method.
But you can filter by name of request and exclude the name of your request using filter input in network tab and regular expression like on the screen below.

```
^((?!draft).)*$
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOSdU.jpg)